# debian cron.hourly script not executing

Tags: debian, cron, scripting

New to cron on debian 9 , I have a file called `ipupdate` in `/etc/cron.hourly/ipupdate`

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 132 Jul 11 18:21 ipupdate`

the file has a single `curl` command like this:

```
curl "https://..."
```

if I run the script manually it runs just fine

in my logs I see:

`Jul 17 14:17:02 dpi CRON[12248]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

the script is not being executed (my ip is not updated), why ? how can I troubleshoot please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible reasons.

A common problem is that the environment is not what the script expects. In particular, it might be that some programs are not in $PATH, although curl is probably part of your distribution and therefor in the standard PATH.

You should add a line #!/bin/sh at the top of the file.

In the script, you can add the line

```
exec >> /tmp/log 2>&1
```

Then if the file is not created, the script is not executed. If the file is created, check for clues why is doesn't work.